# I want to find only the duplicated words and count them, but to ignore that unique words (non-duplicated words)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

Here is the command like:

```
echo "zebra ant spider spider ant zebra ant dog shark" | xargs -n1 | sort | uniq -c | xargs
```

Result:

```
3 ant 1 dog 1 shark 2 spider 2 zebra
```

I want to ignore the unique words (dog and shark, so they are not duplicated words) and to find only the duplicated words with number count.

Comment: check the `uniq` man page: add `-d`

Comment: I thought `-d` is an alphanumeric order, as according to `man`.

Comment: That's not what it means on Linux (or any other POSIX system).  Where did you find that man page?

Comment: @GustavoReis are you perhaps confusing the `-d` option of `uniq` with that of `sort` (`-d, --dictionary-order`)?

Comment: It is what I thought. The `man` said `-d` is `--dictionary-order` and `considers blanks and alphanumerics`, I thought that it means it orders alphabetically in the dictionary-like style.

Comment: @GustavoReis but are you looking at `man uniq` - or `man sort`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "zebra ant spider spider ant zebra ant dog shark" |\
  fmt -1 | sort | uniq -cd | xargs echo
3 ant 2 spider 2 zebra
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for `xargs`:

```
echo $(printf '%s\n' zebra ant spider spider ant zebra ant dog shark | 
       sort | uniq -dc)
```

Output:

```
3 ant 2 spider 2 zebra
```

Answer (score 0):

With gnu awk for PROCINFO :

```
echo "zebra ant spider spider ant zebra ant dog shark" |
awk '
  BEGIN { PROCINFO[ "sorted_in" ] = "@ind_str_asc" }
  { for ( i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++ ) a[$i]++ }
  END {
    for ( i in a ) if( a[i] > 1 ) {
      b = b c a[i] " " i
      c = " "
    }
    print b
  }'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below method

Command

```
echo "zebra ant spider spider ant zebra ant dog shark" | sed "s/ /\n/g"| awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a) print x,a[x]}'| awk '$2 != "1" {print $0}'
```

output

```
echo "zebra ant spider spider ant zebra ant dog shark" | sed "s/ /\n/g"| awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a) print x,a[x]}'| awk '$2 != "1" {print $0}'

zebra 2
ant 3
spider 2
```